# Dual of piecewise defined function

Tags: optimization

I am stuck with the following optimization problem:

$$\min_w \sum_j (\max\{0,w^Tx_j\}-b_j)^2 $$

the $x_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b_j>0$ are given and i am searching the w minimizing this. My approach was to find a constrained dual formulation. But up to now I have not found anything reasonable. I got to the following formulation:

$$\min_{w,t} \sum_j (t_j-b_j)^2 $$
s.t.
$$w^Tx_j < t_j$$
$$w^Tx_j t_j \geq 0$$

Without the second constraint, when $w^Tx_j<0 \Rightarrow t_j = b_j$ at the optimum. But optimizing this formulation with the second constraint is rather horrible.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Your formulation is not good. The minimum becomes trivially at $w=0$ and $t_j=b_j$, but this is not what the original problem would have.

Comment: I agree. There are a few problems with this formulation. I have the feeling that I am missing a tool to solve this.